# Powershell Convert Process-list into HTML

Tags: html, powershell

Export Name and the status of the first 10 services into a html file and color the lines with Running green and Stopped red.

This was the task.

I tried to:

```
Get-Service | Select-Object -First 10 -Property Name,Status
Get-Service | Select-Object -First 10 -Property Name,Status | ConvertTo-Html  > first.txt

(Get-Content hallo.txt) -replace '<td>','<td style="color:#00ff00">'|Set-Content final.html
```

But now I have the problem that everything is green. 
How do I manage to distinguish between Stopped and Running?

I think this idea I've been trying to come up with isn't working.
Maybe you could make the distinction before you export the processes to the file? But I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are sticking with the theme of text replacement, you could do the following:

```
$html = Get-Service | Select-Object -First 10 -property Name,Status |
    ConvertTo-Html | Foreach-Object {
        if ($_ -match '<td>Stopped</td>') {
            $_ -replace '<td>','<td style="color:red">'
        }
        elseif ($_ -match '<td>Running</td>') {
            $_ -replace '<td>','<td style="color:green">'
        }
        else {
            $_ 
        }
    }
$html | Set-Content final.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
Get-Service | Select -First 10 -Property Name,Status | ConvertTo-Html | Foreach { 
  Switch -regex ($_) {
    ".*<td>Stopped</td>.*" { $_ -replace '<td>','<td style="color:red">' }  
    ".*<td>Running</td>.*" { $_ -replace '<td>','<td style="color:green">' 
  }
} | Set-Content "Filepath"
```